# Evaluating a List of Functions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of scalar functions of two variables. Say, it is:

```
list1 = {Sin[x]*Cos[y], Exp[x] - Log[y] + x^2, sin[x], Sin[x]/Sec[y]}
```

I have another list containing the inputs to each scalar function in the list:

```
list2 = {{0.5,0.6},{0.6,0.7},{0.7,0.8},{0.8,0.9}}
```

How do I evaluate each function in `list1` at the values `x` and `y` corresponding to the relevant position in `list2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MapThread[Function[{x, y}, #] @@ #2 &, {list1, list2}]
```

> ```
> {0.395687, 2.53879, sin[0.7], 0.445916}
> ```

---

Old misunderstood:

```
list1 /. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ list2

{
 {0.395687, 2.40955, sin[0.5], 0.395687}, 
 {0.431862, 2.53879, sin[0.6], 0.431862}, 
 {0.448831, 2.7269, sin[0.7], 0.448831}, 
 {0.445916, 2.9709, sin[0.8], 0.445916}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting a list where each entry is a single real number? Implicitly, I have assumed that the first entry in `list2` corresponds to `x` and the second entry in `list2` corresponds to `y.`

Comment: As I understand it the OP only wants the diagonal of your result...

Comment: What I want is that the first "function" in list 1 is evaluate at the first entry in list 2, the second "function" in list 1 is evaluate at the second entry in list 2  and so on.

Comment: @sebhofer thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

another version

```
list1 /. {x -> #1, y -> #2} & @@@ list2

{{0.395687, 2.40955, sin[0.5], 0.395687},
 {0.431862, 2.53879, sin[0.6], 0.431862},
 {0.448831, 2.7269, sin[0.7],  0.448831},
 {0.445916, 2.9709, sin[0.8], 0.445916}}
```